# Can I use and distrubute code posted on JSFiddle

Tags: copyright, intellectual-property, code-snippets

I'd like to use code posted on JSFiddle in a project but do I have permission to do so?

I read the [terms of service](https://jsfiddle.net/terms)  
but they do not mention anything about licensing the code they host. Instead its the typical stuff, JSFiddle has no liability, warranty, etc.

Their intellectual property section does not mention using posted code, does this mean all rights are reserved to JSFiddle?

Comment: Where did you see that code posted? Normally JSFiddle is linked from a chat or a blog post. You should go to that blog post where the author posted it to see if she said something about the license.

Comment: I see JSFiddle also has an "Author" section at least on some posts; if you can't find where it was posted you could try to contact the author and ask for a license.

Comment: @Brandin Yes I think I'll do that, I found the JSFiddle by searching for certain feature implementation and the fiddle itself was the top result that came up, not a blog post or anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While there is a license from the code snippet authors to the code snippet hosting site, there is no license from anyone to you.

In absence of an explicit license, all rights are reserved. You have the right to *look* at the code snippets, but nothing else.